# Problems Running django-autocomplete-light test_application

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

So I have a virtualenv with the following installed modules:

```
Django (1.7.7)
django-autocomplete-light (2.1.0rc3, /Users/username/.virtualenvs/testaclite/src/autocomplete-light)
django-autoslug (1.7.2)
django-cities-light (3.1.2)
pip (6.0.8)
setuptools (12.0.5)
six (1.9.0)
South (1.0.2)
Unidecode (0.4.17)
```

Using the following instructions from the README.rst file that comes with the test project for django-autocomplete-light, I then go to the folder `/Users/username/.virtualenvs/testaclite/src/autocomplete-light/test_project`

I then execute `./manage.py runserver` and get the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

What's going on here? How can I debug this and move forward?

Answer (score 1):

This specific problem was due to an oversight on my part. I did not have my python virtual environment activated. Therefore, python was not being loaded at that moment.

Hopefully, others will benefit from this and not make the same mistake I did.

That being said, the test_project still doesn't fully work. It is full of page not found errors. Maybe it will be repaired / updated soon.

Answer (score 0):

The README has just been fixed, sorry about that.

There was two mistakes in the README:

- https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/commit/d23d2ce0aaf1b657e95486e47a2fe1b10242e257
- https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/commit/5d36be09f0fa3055fc785f2c4d048f927eb57792

I hope everything is working now, feel free to ping us with your question URL on #yourlabs on IRC or on the mailing list.